# Can't login by IE 8 on private domain, Firefox & Chrome work fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, session-variables

I'm deploying a .NET website on a private domain.  Trying to login using IE 8 (the only allowed browser) just refreshes the log-in screen back, and can't redirect to next page.

Some notes:
 - Problem never occurs with Firefox or Chrome (so probably not a
   security issue).
 - There are already other websites published on the same network that    use IE-8 with no problem.
 - Tried to disable all javascripts in both login.aspx and Master page.
 - Tried to add 
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>`
 with different values in "content" (IE=8, IE=EmulateIE8...) with no luck.

- Running the application from VS solution on deployment server works
  fine, but after publishing on IIS, same problem occurs.

Any suggestions??

Edit:
I could narrow the resolution area: IE 8 does not keep session variables!  I tried to redirect the login to a plain page that doesn't use session variables and it worked.  Also, when I replaced the session variable with a constant value in the directed page, it worked.  So the questions becomes: how to preserve session variables between pages programmatically?

Comment: Can you specify the bindings of the Server - SSL only or something mixed?
Also do a trace with f12 Tools, to see if the cookies are possibly actively deleted by the server and all expected cookies are present.  
Last but not least, tell your managers to ditch IE8 ;)

Comment: SSL Settings is disabled for this application.  However the same website is perfectly browsed on FF and Chrome with http not https.
Our application doesn't use cookies, it only uses session variables.  I totally agree with you, so I need to google on "How to convince a client to ditch IE" :)  Thanks anyway

Comment: How are the browsers and the session id correlated? Magic? Cookies or URL-Parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
I spent weeks in this problem before I found, by chance, that IE8 cannot keep session variables/cookies for URLs that contain "underscore" in the domain name!!  Thanks to the [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/d75add8d-d927-4cae-bfc2-5bf41a771204/cookie-not-passing-in-ie8-where-underscore-is-present-in-url-on-32bit-x64-system-server-iis-7?forum=iewebdevelopment) link.

I still don't know if there's a workaround to make IE accept the underscore without changing the domain name.  But at least we have a baseline solution for the client.
Cheers

Comment: Just for the record - from Wikipedia:
The Internet standards (Requests for Comments) for protocols mandate that component hostname labels may contain only the ASCII letters 'a' through 'z' (in a case-insensitive manner), the digits '0' through '9', and the hyphen ('-'). [...] **No other symbols, punctuation characters, or white space are permitted.**